# WYSIWYG editor disappeared on mac Prestashop1.6

Tags: tinymce, prestashop, wysiwyg

I have a problem with the WYSIWYG text editor of my prestashop 1.6. Indeed this one is present and works correctly on Windows but when I test on a Mac Os, it replaces the WYSIWYG by my text framed by HTML tag.

After watching what happens in my console I realize that it returns the following error:

[See error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFH3e.png)

I'm talking about the following line: Fail to load resource: net: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I try to update through the site TinyMCE to put the latest version but no it does not change anything. I regenerate the .htaccess file of the site but nothing either. If someone with an idea and an early solution or solution I am interested.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you try with another browser? Sometimes browser extensions block resources.

Comment: i try on Chrome, Safari and Firefox and i have the same problem... I have uninstall all on this browser and reinstate them but the problem is stil here

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means that the domain name cannot be resolved by the browser so you would need to determine why the browser is telling you that when trying to access the file.